# How do I convert a C union to delphi?

Tags: c, delphi

I am converting the C library to Delphi.
I have a problem converting the code below.
This is the structure used for communications, so the order must be correct.

Delphi

```
Tparam_union_params_t = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (param_float:single);
    1: (param_int32:Int32);
    2: (param_uint32:UInt32);
    ...
    ...
end;

Tparam_union_t = packed record
  param:Tparam_union_params_t // This method requires var name.
  type:UInt8;
end;
```

C Lang

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
  #define PACKED( __Declaration__ ) __Declaration__ __attribute__((packed))
#else
  #define PACKED( __Declaration__ ) __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) __Declaration__ __pragma( pack(pop) )
#endif

PACKED(
typedef struct param_union {
    union {
        float param_float;
        int32_t param_int32;
        uint32_t param_uint32;
        int16_t param_int16;
        uint16_t param_uint16;
        int8_t param_int8;
        uint8_t param_uint8;
        uint8_t bytes[4];
    }; // This no-named union. no-named is important.
    uint8_t type;
}) param_union_t;
```

My method requires var name
but original c code is no-named.
How do I convert anonymous union or structure in C to Delphi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is not bad, but in my article [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#unions) I describe a slightly nicer technique to handle such a union without a name:

```pascal
param_union_p = ^param_union_t;
param_union_t = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (param_float: Single);
    1: (param_int32: Int32);
    2: (param_uint32: UInt32;    // add the members after the union to the largest branch.
        &type: UInt8);
    3: (param_int16: Int16);
    ...
    ...
end;
PParamUnion = ^TParamUnion;
TParamUnion = param_union_t;
```

Instead of in the `UInt32` branch it could also be added to the `Single` or `Int32` branch of the same size. That would still result in the same memory layout as the struct in C, with `&type` at offset 4, and the size of the record being 5, and that is all that counts. Just take a look at the diagram in the article for clarification:

[image]

This way, there is no need to give the union part its own type and its own name. If you don't trust the "trick", use the [code I give in the same article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#conversion) to check the offsets in C and in Delphi.

Borland and Embarcadero, and also Delphi-JEDI, use(d) the same trick to translate anonymous unions, and the Delphi `TVarRec` (for `array of const` parameters) and `TVarType` (for Variants) records are built that way too.

Comment: Thanks! I have 1 question your code.  why use pointer param_union_p and PParamUnion? I want to teach about it because I lack experience. :)

Comment: I have converted many API headers, and it always makes sense to declare pointer types and pretty (Delphi-like) names too, i.e. without un_der_scores and CamelCapped. the _t suffix in C and C++ generally has the same meaning as the T prefix in Delphi, so for a pointer I used a _p suffix where one would use a P prefix in Delphi. Lines like `PSomething = ^TSomething;` are quite common in such translations.